# how to use offset property of ng2-tag-input component?

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to design a custom drop-down using ng2-tag-input. [This](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ng2-tag-input) is the link I use for reference. However I am unable to set `offset` property for `TagInputDropdownComponent`.

Details about offset in docs:

> offset - [?string]
>   Offset to adjust the position of the dropdown with absolute values (defaults to '0 0')

Here's my HTML code:

```html
<tag-input-dropdown [offset]="0 0" [autocompleteObservable]='autocompleteItems$' [identifyBy]="'email'" [displayBy]="'userName'">
```

But I end up with following error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token '0' at column 3 in [0 0] in ng:///AppModule/UserComponent.html@2:57

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Answer by @Romain solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

From author :

https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/issues/162

you should specify like this :

```
<tag-input-dropdown [offset]="'0 0'" [autocompleteObservable]='autocompleteItems$' [identifyBy]="'email'" [displayBy]="'userName'">
```